# Expo edges not working in Unity?

Tags: 11.10, unity

Expo edge bindings and keyboard bindings don't work at all for me after upgrading to  11.10.  They worked fine in 11.04.  Now the only way I can get the expo view is via the Unity sidebar icon.  Anyone know how to fix this?    I really like the edge bindings.

(Yes, I'm sure expo is enabled, and I've tried various combinations of keyboard/edge settings in compiz config settings manager)

Comment: I have the same problem. For now I use Super-S to get to the workspaces, Ctrl-Alt-D to get to the Desktop.

Comment: Edge Flip Move has stopped working for me in 12.04. Not with the switch to 12.04, but sometime after an update.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Desktop Wall Plugin is config that you need to set, under ccsm -> Desktop Wall -> Edge Flipping Tab

[image]

Check Edge Flip Move and Edge Flip Dnd

Also el for Expo Edge  in ccsm-> Expo -> Bindings tab